# Blocking all users from editing a table, then restoring their rights afterwards, in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to block all users but the superuser from doing any kinds of changes (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc. to `table1`.

Later I want to restore the users' abilities to do so as they were before.

I am not aware of any special existing `GRANT`s.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If no privileges have been granted on a table, only superusers and the table owner can use the table. `REVOKE` all permissions from the table owner, then you have your desired state.

To later restore the privileges, you could later

```
GRANT ALL ON table_name TO table_owner;
```

A simple alternative might be to revoke the `USAGE` privilege on the schema that contains the tables. That would also prevent access to the tables.

Comment: Thank you! And how would I restore the rights later on?